# How to get the missing contents of storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode6, storyboard

I have a problem that I have designed my app on another machine, zipped that project and then I used that zipped file on different machine though my application is working fine however in storyboard I am unable to see the contents in the view controller. For example on the first view controller I have used 2 textfields and buttons but these items now not visible on a different machine where I am trying to see it.

One more thing I would like to add the machine where I designed and cresed my app has Xcode6.3.1 and the machine on which I am trying to run this has Xcode6.4

Comment: are you using size classes?

Comment: Thank you Saheb Roy.. I appreciate your help. Yes I was using the size class and I have selected the class on which I have designed it...

Comment: @Garima it may be due to size classes value change, try to make your size classes as it was previously. if it was compact X Regular then make it as is. i hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your view controllers's controls or views are not visible as you got to set your size class as it was when you added the views, if you change that then those previous views wouldn't be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Because your width and height properties are Any i think. You should change them to previous setting in the bottom of Storyboard.

[image]